# Powerbi Formula.Firewall Error on loading python script

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables (dataframe1 and dataframe2) already loaded in the powerbi.
Their Advanced editor looks like this

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\name\Desktop\table1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table2_Sheet = Source{[Item="Table2",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table2_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Color", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\name\Desktop\table2.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Color", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

And I started a blank query and added this to the advanced editor

```
let
    Source = Python.Execute("# Python:#(lf)",[df1=dataframe2, df2=dataframe1])
in
    Source
```

But when I run this I get an error saying- "Formula.Firewall: Query 'Table' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination."

What is the issue over here? When I ignore the privacy then everything loads up but I don't want to do that. How can I fix this issue in powerBi?

Answer (score 1):

The *Formula Firewall* is quite finicky sometimes.

There is a excellent blog post about it [The Power User – Data Privacy and the Formula Firewall in Power BI / Power Query](https://www.thepoweruser.com/2019/03/12/data-privacy-and-the-formula-firewall/).

Also, a shorter one that goes directly into workaround with the help of a function: [Formula.Firewall Error Referencing Queries - R & Python Scripts](https://sqlitybi.com/formula-firewall-error-referencing-queries-r-python-scripts/)